# WFS GetFeature from coordinate

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, getfeature

I am using Openlayers with Tiled Layers, and when I click on a map (and get the clicked coordinate), I would like to query a (GeoServer) WFS GetFeature service to see if I clicked on a Feature. (I can do something simlar in WMS but want to try to do this with WFS).

The GetFeature requests takes a bounding box as a parameter, so I was thinking I could build a bounding box based upon a coordinate somehow?  This would allow the click to be a little fuzzy - you wouldn't have to click precisely on the point.

I also see there is some searching capabilities with "CQL_FILTER" I may be able to use?

```
let viewProjection = "EPSG:3857";

map.on("singleclick", function(evt) {

    let clickedCoordinate = evt.coordinate;

    let params = {
        service: "WFS",
        version: "1.1.0",
        request: "GetFeature",
        typename: "myWorkspace:myFeature",
        srsname: viewProjection,
        outputFormat: "application/json",
        //CQL_FILTER: CAN THIS BE USED???
        //bbox: HOW DO I BUILD A BOX AROUND THE COORDINATE??
    };

        $.ajax(url, {
            type: "GET",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).then(data => {
            // SUCCESS
        }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            // FAIL
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting bbox coordinates, you can get the coordinates from `evt.coordinate` and use pixel resolution for your zoom using https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#getResolutionForZoom.
Your bbox will be (if not tolerance e.g 1 pixels)

```
var resolutionForZoom = map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(map.getView().getZoom());
minx = evt.coordinate[0] - 0.5 * resolutionForZoom
maxx = evt.coordinate[0] + 0.5 * resolutionForZoom
miny = evt.coordinate[1] - 0.5 * resolutionForZoom
maxy = evt.coordinate[1] + 0.5 * resolutionForZoom
```

There are no issue filtering using CQL Filter as long as you know them enough (already done it on a project using OpenLayers and GeoServer)

Comment: This is great but the bounding box is huge, it is way too large and picks up many other features.  How do I make more precise? How did you come up with 0.5?

Comment: 0.5 = half pixel (resolution = distance in meters for a pixel)

Comment: Actually i was trying to use with EPSG:4326 and it was huge, with EPSG:3857 it is very small and seems to miss the mark. (I'm drawing the bounding box on a map to test)

Comment: Add tolerance to improve results. It could be `var tolerance = 3; // 3 pixels` minx = evt.coordinate[0] - tolerance * 0.5 * resolutionForZoom` and `maxx = evt.coordinate[0] + tolerance * 0.5 * resolutionForZoom` Do the same for `miny`, `maxy`

Comment: Can this be adapted to work with the 4326 coordinate system?

Comment: Yes but be aware that a pixel in a projection converted to another one differs from getting the pixel value without changing projection (projections are about deformations)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79852/discussion-between-user210757-and-thomasg77).